# Main entry is missing. App cannot be started. Verify app bootstrap

Tags: angular, electron, nativescript

I have an existing Angular/Electron application that I would like to extend with Nativescript 8. I have installed all the prerequisites and I should be ready to go but I am having issues with my `package.json` file.

I am a little lost at the moment on how I should specify the entry point since my Electron app requires a different entry point then my Nativescript app.

At this point I have three entry files:

- `main.js` (used for electron)
- `src/main.ts` (web)
- `src/main.tns.ts` (nativescript)

In the `package.json` I am currently pointing my main property to `main.js`.

With this setup I am able to run my web and electron apps without issues. However when I try to run the nativescript app with the command `npm run android` I am getting the following output:

```
Searching for devices...
Preparing project...
File change detected. Starting incremental webpack compilation...

webpack is watching the files…

Hash: c60353645ecf0a28f3f3
Version: webpack 4.44.2
Time: 8771ms
Built at: 02-05-2021 23:31:37
Entrypoint bundle = runtime.js vendor.js bundle.js
[../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy recursive] ../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object 160 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app.css] 1.2 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/app-routing.module.tns.ts] 1.34 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.component.tns.ts] 675 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.module.tns.ts] 1.87 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/modules/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component.tns.ts] 1.04 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/modules/pages/pages-routing.module.tns.ts] 1.42 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/modules/pages/pages.component.tns.ts] 736 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/modules/pages/pages.module.tns.ts] 1.26 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./main.ts] 1.9 KiB {bundle} [built]
[~/package.json] external "~/package.json" 42 bytes {bundle} [optional] [built]
    + 548 hidden modules

WARNING in ../node_modules/@nativescript/angular/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/nativescript-angular.js 1786:42-58
"export 'BottomNavigation' was not found in '@nativescript/core'
 @ ./main.ts

WARNING in ../node_modules/@nativescript/angular/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/nativescript-angular.js 1816:40-54
"export 'TabContentItem' was not found in '@nativescript/core'
 @ ./main.ts

WARNING in ../node_modules/@nativescript/angular/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/nativescript-angular.js 1814:34-42
"export 'TabStrip' was not found in '@nativescript/core'
 @ ./main.ts

WARNING in ../node_modules/@nativescript/angular/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/nativescript-angular.js 1815:38-50
"export 'TabStripItem' was not found in '@nativescript/core'
 @ ./main.ts

WARNING in ../node_modules/@nativescript/angular/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/nativescript-angular.js 1817:30-34
"export 'Tabs' was not found in '@nativescript/core'
 @ ./main.ts

WARNING in E:\Food manager\repos\allindex-food-manager\src\main.tns.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.
Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
Webpack build done!
Updating runtime package.json with configuration values...
Project successfully prepared (android)
Restarting application on device emulator-5554...
Successfully synced application org.nativescript.ngsample on device emulator-5554.
JS: Angular is running in development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable production mode.
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.ngsample/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
System.err: Error: Main entry is missing. App cannot be started. Verify app bootstrap.
System.err:
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.ngsample/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
System.err: Error: Main entry is missing. App cannot be started. Verify app bootstrap.
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
System.err: Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
System.err: Error: Main entry is missing. App cannot be started. Verify app bootstrap.
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1302)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1188)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1175)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1153)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1149)
System.err:     at com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:29)
System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
System.err:     ... 9 more
```

If anyone has any suggestion for me I would appreciate it.

More info:
`tsconfig.app.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [
      "googlemaps"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": [
        "src/*.web",
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ]
}
```

`tsconfig.tns.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": [
        "src/*.tns.ts",
        "src/*.ts"
      ]
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "./src/main.ts",
    "./src/main.tns.ts"
  ]
}
```